# What would you like to see in a generic ToString function?

Tags: .net

Lets say you have a generic function called "SafeToString". The purpose is to be able to pass anything in and always get back a sane response without any exceptions. How would you want it to respond to these inputs?

- Null -> Null or String.Empty
- DBNull.Value -> Null, String.Empty, or some text like ""
- Nullable containing a null -> Null, String.Empty, or some text like ""
- FSharpOption containing None  -> Null, String.Empty, or "None"
- FSharpOption containing Some(5)-> "5" or "Some(5)"

Answer (score 3):

This is not answering your question, so forgive me. But you an always use `Convert.ToString()` on objects to avoid getting exceptions. For instance:

```
string x = null;
string a = x.ToString(); // throws exception

string b = Convert.ToString(x); // this is fine
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to be able to distinguish among different sorts of null/empty values.  So I'd favor something like:

- null -> "null"
- DBNull.Value -> "DBNull", or maybe "DBNull.Value" if you value the ability to distinguish the value from the name of the class
- Nullable containing null -> `"null <typename>"`.  Nullables differ from normal nulls in that they have a type associated with them, and it's potentially useful to know about.
- FSharpOption None -> "None"
- FSharpOption Some(5) -> "Some(5)", just as F# usually does, special thanks to Grauenwolf for checking on this.

Comment: If you were to use this to populat a GUI or printed report, whould you still want to it that way?

Comment: I double checked, FSharpOption.ToString in beta 2 will use "Some(5)"

Comment: @Steven, you would lose that information when you pass it to a function.

Comment: @Grauenwolf: If I passed the null string to a function that took an object, then yes.  However, that would be the case if I passed an `int?` that was null.  I guess, more generally, if I pass a null child reference to a method that took the base class reference, it would not be able to distinguish that from passing a null base reference.  Then again, I don't know that we'd even want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement such function using extension method. Extension methods work fine with null input parameters.

And yes, I agree that NullReferenceException caused by ToString is very annoying in logging functionality.

Comment: Oh yes, of course it would be an extension method. The question is more about what would *you* like to see if you were to use it.